# How can I move a user chosen file to a user chosen directory in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make a program that can move any file the user selects into a different folder. I've looked around and gathered some information and put something together but it doesn't quiet work, but it doesn't have give any errors either. Could someone tell me whats wrong with it and or how to fix it? (This is my first test with Visual Studio + C# keep in mind)

Here is the code (inside a button):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string sourceFile = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;

            var dirPath = @"C:\Users\goverpie\Desktop\Server\Plugins\";
            var extn = Path.GetExtension(sourceFile);

            var finalName = sourceFile + extn;
            var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, sourceFile);

            File.Move(sourceFile, targetFilePath);

        }
```

So, the project builds and runs fine, and it opens up the dialog box, but when I choose a file, the dialog box closes as normal and nothing was moved.

Thank you!

Comment: Debug the code and look at what each of the dest/src paths are. Also look at Path.Combine on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sourceFile` string contains `.InitialDirectory` as well as `.FileName`, so (if I read this correctly), selecting **C:\TEMP\myFile.foo** as your target file, the `targetFilePath` would end up being **C:\Users\goverpie\Desktop\Server\Plugins\C:\TEMP\myFile.foo**.  Given that the system will throw an error when it finds a `:` in the path, you're probably not handling the exception that gets thrown and the system is just quitting.

Put a break point at the `File.Move(sourceFile, targetFilePath);` line and see what the values are.  Also, wrap the whole thing in a `try/catch` block and trap exceptions.

Comment: Does that mean that if I were to remove the .Initialdirectory part, it would work properly? (As it would just become the filename, right?) [P.S. When i tried doing so it didn't work. I'll try what you said now]

Comment: So when I check, you're right. How would I make it so that it only copies the file's actual name (myFile.foo for example) rather than the entire path?

Comment: Sorry to keep posting here but, whenever i use SafeFileName, I get this error:
Could not find file 'c:\users\myUsername\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\newPlugin.txt'.

[EDIT] I forgot to add a new variable that kept the path so that I could use File.Move. Thanks again!

Comment: So, is your solution working?  If so, it's good form to accept the answer.